# Is there a reward for collecting Birdie Medals in Golf Story?

Tags: golf-story

Whenever you manage to score a birdie or lower on a hole, you can earn a medal for that hole, which can be seen when viewing the scorecard for that course.

The medals come in three tiers:

- Silver Medal - Birdie (1 under par)
- Gold Medal - Eagle (2 under par)
- Rainbow Medal - Albatross (3 under par)

**Is there any reward for collecting these medals?**

Comment: Not enough information for a good answer, but a reply on a [GameFAQ post](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/210555-golf-story/75831003?page=1#13) stated that after getting 72 medals listed on the start screen, there wasn't any apparent reward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than your save file displaying how many birdie medals you’ve earned, there is no reward for collecting birdie medals. I confirmed this by earning a birdie medal on all 72 holes.

[image: Save file with 72 birdie medals]